# Connecting Azure-Data-Explorer with Azure-Data-Lake-Gen2

Tags: azure, time-series, azure-data-lake, azure-data-explorer

I try to use Azure-Data-Explorer to create time-series of IoT data that is stored in Azure-Data-Lake-Gen2. The folder structure in Azure-Data-Lake is "archive/yyyy/MM/dd/HH/*.json".

The idea is:

1. Create an external table and json mapping (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/data-lake-query-data)
2. Make time-series (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/time-series-analysis)
3. Use analytics to get cool insights ;-)

I've tried for step one (in the Azure-Data-Explorer query):

```
.create external table ExternalAdlGen2 (timestamp:datetime, timestamp2:datetime, deviceId:string, telemetry:dynamic)
kind=adl
partition format_datetime="'year='yyyy/'month='MM/'day='dd/'hour='HH" by bin(timestamp, 1h)
dataformat=json
( 
   @h'abfss://filesystem@<storage acount name>.dfs.core.windows.net/archive/path;sharedkey=<access key>'
)
```

and also:

```
.create external table ExternalAdlGen2 (timestamp:datetime, timestamp2:datetime, deviceId:string, telemetry:dynamic)
kind=adl
partition format_datetime="'year='yyyy/'month='MM/'day='dd/'hour='HH" by bin(timestamp, 1h)
dataformat=json
( 
   @h'abfss://filesystem@<storage acount name>.dfs.core.windows.net/archive/path;sharedkey=<access key>'
)
with 
(
   docstring = "Docs",
   folder = "ExternalTables",
   namePrefix="Prefix"
)
```

The result is the following error message:
"Error I could not parse that, sorry. clientRequestId: KustoWebV2; some_guid"

Do you have any suggestion how to do that properly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was a bug in the documentation which will be fixed shortly.

in the URL specification - please replace `@h'abfss://...` with `h@'abfss://...`

Comment: Hi Yoni, thank you for your reply. The documentation does not have the colon before abfss. Just for my understanding: is the colon needed or not? I tried already without the colon... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right - the colon was a typo (fixed in my reply) and is not required. If this is still not working for you, please share the updated command you tried running

Comment: I tried it from the beginning without the colon. I also tried it with the demo statements from the blog post [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/externaltables). Still not working. Here is the sample Code from mentioned post:

Comment: `.create external table ExternalAdlGen2 (Timestamp:datetime, x:long, s:string) 
kind=adl
partition by bin(Timestamp, 1d)
dataformat=csv
( 
   @h'abfss://filesystem@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/path;secretKey'
)
with 
(
   docstring = "Docs",
   folder = "ExternalTables",
   namePrefix="Prefix"
) `

Comment: your example still uses `@h'` instead of `h@'` - in my original reply i suggested you use the latter

Comment: Thanks @Yoni. I was so much focused on the colon that I didn't recognize the Position of the `@`. Now it is working. Thank you very much!

Comment: Now I am running into the next issue: I cannot create the json mapping as decribed in the documentation. `Èrror Syntax error: Query could not be parsed` I am using the following mapping : `.create external table ExternalTableJson json mapping "mappingName" '[{"column":"rownumber","datatype":"int","path":"$.rownumber"},{"column":"rowguid","path":"$.rowguid"}]'`

Comment: **at the time of writing this comment**, the doc is a little ahead of its time, and your cluster is still not running with a version that supports this command. it is expected to be available within a week or 2